# how to make TAR of selected files in directories

Tags: tar

I have below paths in my system

```
/a/b/z
/c/d/
/e/f/z
/y/g/
```

In "z" directory there are some files i just want to make tar of that files without going into directory .

Comment: Do you want to preserve the rest of the directory structures?  Like should the tar contain `a/b/z/file1` and `e/f/z/file2` or just `file1` and `file2`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your tarfile is `$TARBALL` with an *absolute path*.

```
tar cfC $TARBALL /a/b/z .
tar AfC $TARBALL /e/f/z .
```

The `-C` option changes directory to the next argument. What's not clear is what will happen when files of the same name are in both directories.

The alternative is to keep the path names:

```
tar cf $TARBALL /a/b/z /e/f/z
```

The pathnames will be retained and kept in the tarball and those directories will be created during extraction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your files are like

```
/home/usr/dir1/dir2/a.txt
/home/usr/dir1/dir2/b.txt
/home/usr/dir1/dir3/a.txt
/home/usr/dir1/dir3/b.txt
```

And you want to compress `dir2` and `a.txt` from `dir3`, 
then you can use

```
tar -cvf mytarfile.tar /home/usr/dir1/dir2/ /home/usr/dir1/dir3/a.txt
```

Or just 
do

```
tar -cvf mytarfile.tar dir2 dir3/a.txt
```

staying in directory `dir1` where `dir2` and `dir3` reside.